# Confusion in method applied in solutions of differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, differential

For a 2nd order, homogeneous, linear differential equation, if the auxiliary equation has two equal roots, why can't we use $\ y=Ae^{n_1x}+Be^{n_2x} $ as it's solution?

Moreover, what connection does the amount of arbitrary constants has with the differential equation?

Comment: I know that it will give a result such as $\ y=Ce^{nx}$, but why does that matter?

Comment: I suppose you're talking about 2nd order homogeneous linear differential equations.
As you said it will give you only "one" answer : $C e^{nx}$. However the general solutions is given by the linear combination of two linearly independent solutions : $C_1 f(x) + C_2 g(x)$ and there you only have one term.

Comment: But can't we just present the general solution as $\ y=(A+B)e^{nx}$?

Comment: You suggest to use two functions : $A e^{nx}$ and $B e^{nx}$. However theses functions are not linearly independent.

Comment: Apologies for my ignorance, but can you tell what does linear independence mean here? and why does it matter?

Comment: The space of solutions to a homogeneous, linear differential equation is a vector space under the usual notions of function addition and scalar multiplication; linear independence here is just the usual sense of term from linear algebra.

Comment: I suspect you know but the characteristic equation will give (for repeated roots) a general solution $y(x)=Ae^{nx}+Bxe^{nx}$

Comment: Consider $y'' = -y$. The general solution is given by the linear combination of two linearly independent solutions. For example here we can guess that $sin(x)$ works. So our general solution will look like $C_1 sin(x) +\ ?$ but we need another function which is linearly independent from $sin(x)$. For example $cos(x)$. So the general solution is $C_1 sin(x) + C_2 cos(x)$. Now we need to prove that indeed $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ are L.I. This means we need to prove that $a sin(x) + b cos(x) = 0 \implies a = b = 0$.

Comment: [Second part of comment !] This can be done in the following way : Choose some $x$, say $x = 0$, we then have $a sin(0) + b cos(0) = b = 0$, therefore $b$ must be $0$. Then clearly we have $a sin(x) = 0$ implies $a = 0$, so we proved that $sin(x)$ and $cos(x)$ are indeed L.I.

Comment: Okay but why did we need another function? Can't just multiplying some constant with sin(x) do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So when you try to solve the differential equation (homogeneous second order linear with constant coefficients) you make a guess $f(x) = Ce^{Rx}$ inserting this into the differential equation you get the characteristic equation. Thus $f$ is a solution if and only if $R$ is a root in the characteristic equation.

Now you a case where you get repeated roots. So in effect you have only found one solution, since the other is just the first solution multiplied with a scalar.

Next you utilize the method of "Reduction of order" to get a first order equation that can be used to construct the second solution you are looking for. Please refer to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reduction_of_order) on how to use reduction of order (this is the reason why the second solution is $xe^{Rx}$ for repeated roots).

For the second part of the equation. The order and the number of arbitrary number of constants are the same - if for instance the Lipschitz condition is met.

EDIT:
See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) for more information on the Lipschitz condition, the connection with a existence and uniqueness theorem.

Comment: So for every 2nd order HL differential equation, there has to be two solutions? Why?

Comment: Because of existence and uniqueness theorems. They say that for second order equations you need to know $y(t_0)$ and $y'(t_0)$ in order to have a unique solution. This boils down to setting exactly two constants.

Comment: Oh thanks. Please see if I got this correct. A differential equation can have 1 or more than 1 solution. To achieve a unique solution (for unknown purposes), we try to relate those two solution to get an accurate and a unique solution.